# In Swift 4 how do you properly hide a tabBar?

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller

How do you properly hide a UITabBarController's tabBar using 'hidesBottomBarWhenPushed'?

viewControllerA:

```
hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
```

This succeeds in hiding the tabBar, but it is permanently hidden even when viewControllerA is popped off viewControllerB.

Answer (score 7):

You can simply use this in your `ViewDidLoad()` method.

```
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = true
```

For swift 3.0:

```
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
```

Or you can change z position of tab bar this way:

```
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.layer.zPosition = -1
```

and if you want to show it again then:

```
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.layer.zPosition = 0
```

Answer (score 3):

In viewWillAppear you can hide the tabbarcontroller tab using

```
 self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
 self.tabBarController?.tabBar.layer.zPosition = -1
```

and in ViewWillDisappear show the tab using

```
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.layer.zPosition = -0
```

when you use 'hidesBottomBarWhenPushed' for hiding the tabbar for a particular view controller set that property only for that view controller. i.e, **yourviewcontroller.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true**.

Hope this helps

Comment: This doesn't disappear correctly when you drag the view controller off stack. How do you properly use 'hidesBottomBarWhenPushed'? The answer is something about referencing a different view controller. Not a clue.

Comment: edited my answer . set the hidesBottomBarWhenPushed property on the view controller

Answer (score 3):

For hiding tab bar properly 
Ensure the property 
`tabBarController?.tabBar.isTranslucent = true`

then you can properly hide tabBar **if this property is false it show the black stripe in place of tabBar**.